# How to write a JS lib?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for good practice or pattern to write a lib in JS. I would like to get **good** reference on how to write. Or pattern to follow.

I've just write a lib, but seems to be not good code. So, I am looking for doc in relation to.

Comment: Best thing you can do is see how other ones are written, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Comment: I don't agree that looking at jQuery is a good way to learn. It's too complicated for a novice and there are too many concepts you would need to understand, before learning from it.  Instead I recommend that you solve smaller more immediate problems and ask for code review on your proposed solution. Rather than asking a general question like "how should I write a library", address a particular problem, write a library, and ask for criticism on that proposed solution.

Comment: I think writing a library should not be your goal. Start writing tons of applications and games, in the end you will find things you have written multiple times. Learn design patterns. Wrap repeating functions in a library, but again writing a library just to write a library is kinda pointless.

Comment: Take a look at "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns" by Addy Osmani - http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [dailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/), there is excellent series on how to create a javascript framework, check it out:

- [Let's Make a Framework](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmaf) ([series in pdf format](http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/02/framework-review/))

The features along with tutorials you will be going to learn include:

- Library architectures
- Functional programming
- Selectors
- Events
- Ajax
- Animation
- Module loading
- Plugin architecture

[And here is the result of that great tutorial series, "turningjs" framework](http://turingjs.com/)